# Why is setTimeout so unpopular?

Tags: javascript, performance, timeout, settimeout

I have a weird feeling about Timeout. From one side I hear, it's not good, inefficent etc., but on the other side, there doesn't seem to be another way. Do you have some thoughts on this topic and question in general?

Answer (score 0):

Most people misunderstand how `setTimeout()` works so they end up using it where it is not appropriate. What `setTimeout()` does is to run whatever you pass to it (callback) after a specified period expires. For example, if you look at the snippet below

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Say hello.");
}, 1000)
```

What this does is guarantee that "Say hello." is logged after 1 second expires. This does not mean that it'll happen after exactly 1 second, it might take longer than that but it'll not happen before 1 second has expired. Essentially, when your runtime encounters a `setTimeout()`, a timer is started and the `setTimeout` is removed from the call stack. After the specified time expires, the callback for the `setTimeout()` is pushed onto the task queue. If the call stack is clear, the callback is then pushed to the call stack from the task queue by the event loop. This extra delay might be because there are more items ahead of the callback on your task queue.